# INSERT is creating 4 entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I execute the following query, it adds the same row 4 times into my table.

```
INSERT INTO [Project].[dbo].[Document]  
(
project_id, 
classification_id, 
document_nid, 
number, 
title_1, 
title_2, 
title_3, 
revision, 
revision_description_id, 
date_revision, 
number_external, 
revision_external, 
created_by_id, 
modified_by_id, 
date_modified, 
filename, 
file_extension, 
file_size, 
source_id, 
pdf, 
status_id, 
hidden
)  
SELECT p.id, 
        v.classification, 
        v.nid, 
        v.docNo, 
        v.title1, 
        v.title2, 
        v.title3, 
        v.rev, 
        rd.id, 
        v.dateRevision, 
        v.docNoExt, 
        v.revExt, 
        cr.id, 
        mo.id, 
        v.dateModified, 
        v.filename, 
        v.fileExtension, 
        v.fileSize, 
        co.id, 
        v.pdf, 
        v.status, 
        v.hidden 
FROM (VALUES ('00000001', 80, 4, 'DOC004', 'Title 1', 'Title 2', 'Title 3', '0', 'Final', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL, NULL, 'User Name', 'User Name', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'DOC004' + '_' + '0', '.xlsx', '999 MB', 'MyCompany', 0, 1, 0)) 
        v(project, classification, nid, docNo, title1, title2, title3, rev, revision_description, dateRevision, docNoExt, revExt, created_by, modified_by, dateModified, filename, fileExtension, fileSize, source, pdf, status, hidden) 
    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Project] p 
    ON p.number = v.project 
    LEFT JOIN [MyApp].[dbo].[Revision_Description] rd 
    ON rd.name = v.revision_description 
    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] cr 
    ON cr.first_name + ' ' + cr.last_name = v.created_by
    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] mo 
    ON mo.first_name + ' ' + mo.last_name = v.modified_by
    LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Company] co 
    ON co.name = v.source;
```

I only want 1 entry and I'm not sure why it is entering 4.

The query JOINs 4 tables if that is relevant...

Any help would be appreciated.

I want to re-enable a Unique Key on this table and this is preventing me being able to do that.

Edit:

It's now retrieving 2 rows with the machine_name addition:

```
LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] cr 
ON cr.first_name + ' ' + cr.last_name = v.created_by AND cr.machine_name = 'DESKTOP-01' 
LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] mo 
ON mo.first_name + ' ' + mo.last_name = v.modified_by AND cr.machine_name = 'DESKTOP-01'
```

[image: Results]

If you look at the 2 `id` columns after the 2 `NULL` entries, it is still choosing id = 1 for the first row when it should be id = 2 as per the column before, id 2 is with the correct machine_name.

Comment: One of the joins must have multiple matches. Show us the data returned by the select (i.e.run the query without the insert) to help identify which.

Comment: Dale Burrell thank you for the response. You're right, the select returns 4 rows. I think it because the username appears twice in the User Table, so it is adding a variation "created by" and "modified by" using the id for that entry i.e. "1, 1", "1, 2", "2, 1", "2, 2". Is there a way round this? Can I distinct on one column? Thank you.

Comment: If you have multiple entries in the staff table then how do you identify the correct one? Thats how to solve the issue...

Comment: Thanks dale, I identify the user by the computer name column thank you. Might be better to split this table. Thanks a lot for your help Dale. Really is appreciated.

Comment: I thought it would be as simple as adding `AND cr.machine_name = 'DESKTOP-01' ` to the `LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] mo 
ON mo.first_name + ' ' + mo.last_name = v.modified_by` and `LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] cr 
ON cr.first_name + ' ' + cr.last_name = v.created_by` but this still retrieves 2 rows... I tried it in a WHERE clause also.

Comment: Post some actual data... e.g. `p.id, p.number, rd.name, cr.machine_name, mo.machine_name, co,name`

Comment: Dale, please see modified question with image.

Comment: You've joined twice on `cr.machine_name = 'DESKTOP-01'` instead of the second join being `mo.machine_name = 'DESKTOP-01'`

Comment: YESSS!!! Dale you legend! Thank you very much! Really appreciate your time. I'm still learning so thank you for your patience.