# SQL Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint but entry doesn't exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a bit stuck. I'm getting a UNIQUE KEY violation when I try to insert a new entry into my database, but when I run a select on the value that is supposedly in violation, it returns no results.

I've attached some images of my UNIQUE KEY and also the query returning no results.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The exact error message SQL Management Studio gives is:

```
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UK_Document'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Document'. The duplicate key value is (E-00000001-M-0212-001_0).
The statement has been terminated.
```

```
INSERT INTO [Project].[dbo].[Document]  
                            (
                                project_id, 
                                classification_id, 
                                document_nid, 
                                number, 
                                title_1, 
                                title_2, 
                                title_3, 
                                revision, 
                                revision_description_id, 
                                date_revision, 
                                number_external, 
                                revision_external, 
                                created_by_id, 
                                modified_by_id, 
                                date_modified, 
                                filename, 
                                file_extension, 
                                file_size, 
                                source_id, 
                                pdf, 
                                status_id, 
                                hidden,
                                read_only
                            )  
                            SELECT p.id, 
                                cl.id, 
                                v.document_nid, 
                                v.number, 
                                v.title_1, 
                                v.title_2, 
                                v.title_3, 
                                v.revision, 
                                rd.id, 
                                v.date_revision, 
                                v.number_external, 
                                v.revision_external, 
                                cr.id, 
                                mo.id, 
                                v.date_modified, 
                                v.filename, 
                                v.file_extension, 
                                v.file_size, 
                                co.id, 
                                v.pdf, 
                                ds.id, 
                                v.hidden, 
                                v.read_only 
                            FROM 
                            (
                                VALUES 
                                (
                                    '00000001', 
                                    NULL, 
                                    1, 
                                    'E-00000001-M-0212-001', 
                                    'XREF TEST', 
                                    '', 
                                    '', 
                                    '0', 
                                    'For Construction', 
                                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                    '', 
                                    '', 
                                    'Bill Gates', 
                                    'Bill Gates', 
                                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
                                    'E-00000001-M-0212-001_0', 
                                    '.dwg', 
                                    '12 kb', 
                                    'My Company', 
                                    0, 
                                    'working', 
                                    0, 
                                    1
                                )
                            ) 
                            v
                            (
                                project, 
                                classification, 
                                document_nid, 
                                number, 
                                title_1, 
                                title_2, 
                                title_3, 
                                revision, 
                                revision_description, 
                                date_revision, 
                                number_external, 
                                revision_external, 
                                created_by, 
                                modified_by, 
                                date_modified, 
                                filename, 
                                file_extension, 
                                file_size, 
                                source, 
                                pdf, 
                                status, 
                                hidden, 
                                read_only
                            ) 
                            LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Project] p 
                                ON p.number = v.project 
                            LEFT JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Revision_Description] rd 
                                ON rd.name = v.revision_description 
                            LEFT JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Document_Status] ds 
                                ON ds.description = 'working' 
                            LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] cr 
                                ON cr.full_name = v.created_by 
                            LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[User] mo 
                                ON mo.full_name = v.modified_by 
                            LEFT JOIN [MyCompany].[dbo].[Company] co 
                                ON co.name = v.source 
                            INNER JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Area] ar 
                                ON ar.name = 'Projects' 
                            INNER JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Category] ca 
                                ON ca.name = 'Engineering' 
                            INNER JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Discipline] di 
                                ON di.name = 'MECHANICAL & PIPING' 
                            INNER JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Document_Type] dt1 
                                ON dt1.name = 'DRAWINGS' 
                            INNER JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Document_Type_2] dt2 
                                ON dt2.name = 'XREF' 
                            INNER JOIN [DMS].[dbo].[Classification] cl 
                                ON ar.id = cl.area_id AND ca.id = cl.category_id AND di.id = cl.discipline_id AND dt1.id = cl.document_type_id AND dt2.id = cl.document_type_2_id;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Clearly your `JOIN`s end up producing a result set where your one row ends up being multiplied. In other words, the `INSERT` *itself* produces the duplicate rows, they're not there in the table yet. Check the output of the `SELECT` without the `INSERT`.

Comment: Try `SELECT DISTINCT...`

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for your response, you're right. The SELECT returns 9 rows. Is this an effect of using the wrong JOIN?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin thank you for your response, SELECT DISTINCT didn't work.

Comment: The problem seems to be with created_by and modified_by, they are bringing back a combination of results.

Comment: This is the [second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586045/insert-is-creating-4-entries) you have encountered the same problem - validate your select query **before** you insert (or update or delete) the result.

Answer (score 0):

All, thank you for our responses. The problem was Bill Gates was entered 3 times in the User table. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

The query you are trying to run is a single transaction. If there is an error, it will be rollbacked automatically. So please check your select query and make sure that, your file name is unique over there.